# Group value via range and value sql query

Tags: sql-server, sorting, filter, grouping

I have two table .
Table1 have following fields.

```
From    To      id
----    ----     ----
  0      0        1
  1      5        2
  5      10       3
  10     15       4
```

Table 2:

```
Table 1 ID    Value
---------     -------
1              10
2              10
3              15
4              10
```

current output:

```
from      To     Value
-----  ------   -------
0         15      10
5         10      15
```

Required Output

```
From     To     Value
------   ----   ------ 
0         5      10
5         10     15
10        15     10
```

How get the output like

code

```
SELECT  MIN(DiscountFrom) FromDiscount ,
    MAX(DiscountTo) Todiscount ,
    Amount
FROM    table1 t1
    JOIN table2  t2 ON t1.id =  t2.id
GROUP BY Amount
```

Comment: And where is your code ?

Comment: I am confused by your data, sometimes the to  value of the previous record matches the from value of the next, but this does not happen for the first and second records, please clarify

Answer (score 0):

Here for me grouping makes no sense  so, i used `lead()` function to access next record if 0 found

```
select distinct 
       case when t.[from] = 1 then 0 else t.[from] end [from],  
       case when t.[to] = 0 then lead(t.[to]) over (order by t.id) else t.[to] end [to], 
       t1.value 
from table1 t
join table2 t1 on t1.id = t.id
```

Result :

```
from    to  value
0       5   10
5      10   15
10     15   10
```

Comment: This will not work in all situations e.g. if there are 3 similar values in a row , and relies on key order,

Comment: @RegBes the above is posted based on current scenario or data which provided.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data is inconsistent, for this to work i had to change the first record to

```
From    To      id
----    ----     ----
  0      1        1
```

then this works for all cases

```
;WITH test1
     AS (SELECT
           t.id
           ,[from]
           ,[to]
           ,value
         FROM
           table1 t
           JOIN table2 t1
             ON t1.id = t.id),
     MyTest
     AS (SELECT
           Anchor.[from]
           ,Anchor.[To]
           ,Anchor.value
           ,1 AS Grp
         FROM
           test1 AS Anchor
         WHERE
           [From] = 0
         UNION ALL
         SELECT
           Child.[from]
           ,Child.[To]
           ,Child.value
           ,CASE WHEN Mytest.value = child.value THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + MyTest.Grp AS grp
         FROM
           test1 AS Child
           INNER JOIN MyTest
                   ON Mytest.[To] = child.[From])
SELECT
  Min([From]) AS [From]
  ,Max([To])  AS [To]
  ,Max(Value) AS Value
FROM
  mytest
GROUP  BY
  Grp
```